# definition of a random vector space

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I am reading Vershynin's high dimensional probability theory book and I got confused by "several" definitions of an $m$-dimensional random vector subspace of the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$.

(a) An $m$-dimensional random vector subspace $E$ of $\mathbb R^n$ is the column span of a random $n\times m$ Gaussian random matrix $G$ with i.i.d $N(0,1)$ entries.

(b) An $m$-dimensional random vector subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ is a random variable $X$ taking values in the metric measure space $(G_{n,m},d,\mathbb P)$ where $G_{n,m}$ is Grassmann manifold and  $d(E,F)=\|P_E-P_F\|$ where $P_E,P_F$ are projections onto these $m$-dim subspaces. The $\mathbb P$ is a normalized Haar measure on it. （According to the book, it seems that it is uniform.）

Here are my questions:

(1) What's the definition of a uniform measure on $G_{n,m}$ are why is $\mathbb P$ uniform?

(2) Are these two definitions equivalent under some assumptions? What is the connection between them? Note the distribution in (a) is so special, namely $N(0,1)$.

Comment: It all flows from the rotational symmetry of the multidimensional standard Gaussian, the same fact that underlies the polar coordinates proof of the $\sqrt{2\pi}$ norming constant.

Comment: @kimchilover You mean one can really start with b to show that the random subspaces are spanned by normalized Gaussian random vectors?

Comment: This is the content of a series of papers by A. T. James, https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177705994 for one, along these lines.  I don't have time now to look up modern textbook references to this result.

Comment: The Haar measure and the uniform distribution are beyond the scope of Vershynin's book. Briefly speaking, the Haar measure is a measure that is rotationally invariant in this context. The uniform measure means that any ball of a fixed radius $r$ (this is well-defined as you have a distance for the Grassmannians) has the same measure. It isn't difficult to verify these two points.